# How can I check if the admin bar is visible to the current user?

Tags: users, user-roles, admin-bar

I'm new to WordPress. I would like to know

- Is the admin bar visible to all users and roles?
- If not, how can I check it is visible to the current user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`is_admin_bar_showing()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin_bar_showing) to check if the *currently logged in user* is

1. logged in
2. has activated the admin bar in his user settings/preferences